# I've got an auto-generated list that's not accepting the onclick method

Tags: android-layout, listview

I've got this auto-generated list

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"    
    android:onClick="onClick"       />
```

And the debugger fails on grabbing the "android:onClick" method,

I'm trying to get a specific item that's "long-clicked" and delete it, I have the delete working, and I know I need to get the

```
position = lv.getPositionForView(view);
(Object) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
```

but I'm not sure how to make the listener and attach it to code to do this. Any ideas?

I've got this in my onCreate method:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    lv.setOnLongClickListener( new View.OnLongClickListener() { 
        @ Override 
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);
            Log.d(TAG, "position in here: " + position);
            if (getListAdapter().getCount() > 0) {
                Encouragement encouragement = (Encouragement) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                datasource.deleteEncouragement(encouragement);
                adapter.remove(encouragement);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            return false;
        } 
    });
```

but it's not reaching the 
    Log.d(TAG, "position in here: " + position);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this code to work out a solution

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item "+arg1);
        return false;
} });
```

The problem was that I wasn't selecting a specific item from the list, just a general item was confusing the compiler.